# How to Install and Use Boost?

Tags: c++, boost

I am new to C++ and am trying to install and use the Boost libraries for the first time.  I am attempting to compile and example of high resolution timing:

```
#include <boost/timer/timer.hpp>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
   boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer t;

   for (long i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
      std::sqrt(123.456L); // burn some time

   return 0;
}
```

However, when I attempt to compile this I seem not to be picking up the bath to the boost libraries:

```
$ g++ -Wall -I ~/boost_1_53_0 boost_cpu_timer.cc
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer::auto_cpu_timer(short)", referenced from:
        _main in ccQSlF30.o
    "boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer::~auto_cpu_timer()", referenced from:
        _main in ccQSlF30.o
    "boost::system::generic_category()", referenced from:
        __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)in ccQSlF30.o
    "boost::system::system_category()", referenced from:
       __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)in ccQSlF30.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I installed boost with the suggested commands:

```
$ tar xzfv boost_1_53_0.tar.bz2
$ cd boost_1_53_0
$ ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/local
$ sudo ./b2 --prefix=/usr/local install
```

Which installed some dynamic libraries in /usr/local, ie 
    $ ls /usr/local/lib/
    ...
    libboost_timer.a
    libboost_date_time.a
    libboost_timer.dylib
    ...

But I am still not making the connection how to compile C++ code with boost headers eg

```
#include <boost/timer/timer.hpp>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing you need to link the boost_timer library.  In g++ this is done by appending `-llibraryName`, or in your case, `-lboost_timer`.

Comment: Awesome, did the trick, thanks.  
$ g++ -Wall -lboost_timer -lboost_system boost_cpu_timer.cc
Do you know of a good reference to learn more about linking in C++?  I ask because this would not have been intuitive for me, as a newbie it seems like Id want to put the boost directory in the include path,  but I had no knowledge of the linking.

Comment: usually, compilers will only link the stl in by default.  for g++ (clang, icc, etc.) you can specify new libraries to link in by -lname, and new places to look for libraries by -Lpath

Comment: In general, linking is compiler defined, so you'll have to lookup documentation for your compiler.

Comment: @DavidWilliams, you should list libraries at the end of the link line:  `g++ -Wall boost_cpu_timer.cc -lboost_timer -lboost_system`  In general libraries need to come after the objects that depend on them, linker order matters

Comment: The Boost Getting Started docs include a brief section on linking to their libs: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#link-your-program-to-a-boost-library