# Boost_chrono lib not being installed

Tags: c++, boost, c++-chrono

I am trying to get a precise time-stamp for C++ using boost_chrono, however I am for some reason unable to get the boost_chrono library linked.

I've followed the following steps:

1. Downloaded boost 1.53.0
2. Extracted the files, and ran `sudo ./bjam` in the folder's root.
3. No idea where the libraries have been put, they aren't in my `/usr/lib` folder, so ran `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`.
4. Boost libraries are now in `/usr/lib` however `boost_chrono` is not there.

I am getting the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_chrono
```

`libboost_chrono.a` is in `boost_1_53_0/stage/lib` and `boost_1_53_0/bin.v2/libs`, but adding these as library search paths doesn't help.

I am adding

```
-lboost_filesystem -lboost_chrono -lboost_system
```

to the C++ compiling.

Does anyone have any advice for this? So much documentation for anything library-related is very opaque to the ~beginner and I don't seem to be getting anywhere.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check /usr/local/lib?

Answer (score 2):

Your apt-get install probably didn't do what you want because it installs the system package for Boost, which might well be too old to include Chrono, which is pretty recent.

As for the other, I'm not sure what bjam without any arguments does exactly, but it doesn't do an install; for that you have to call ./bjam install.

The easiest way is probably to just follow the [Getting Started instructions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html) from the Boost docs. Scroll down a bit to get to the part about compiled libraries.

Answer (score 2):

I got it working using [How to Install and Use Boost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300876/how-to-install-and-use-boost?rq=1) which I hadn't found before:

"
I installed boost with the suggested commands:

```
$ cd boost_1_53_0
$ ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/local
$ sudo ./b2 --prefix=/usr/local install
```

"

Boost then successfully installed to `/usr/local`, and I included `/usr/local/include` and added library search path `/usr/local/lib`.

Importantly, I then required `sudo ldconfig` before it linked correctly.

Thanks to those who helped, much appreciated.